# How do I identify duplicate rows in an Excel cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have an excel file with thousands of rows of contact info.

I need to get a list of all the rows that have duplicate first and last names.

I have been able to use conditional formatting to highlight the rows that have duplicate names, but I want to be able to get a list of all of the duplicates.

As an example, my list looks like this:

```
 First Name    Last    Email               Phone
 Tim           Berly   tim@gmail.com       454-343-2123
 Tim           Berly   tim43@gamil.com     343-234-2343
 Mary          Berly   bm@mdmdfm.com       333-212-6996
 Jill          Brown   jbrown@mgasd.com    334-343-3443
 Mary          Red     maryr@gmai.com      444-454-4545
 Mary          Red     redmary@yahoo.com   333-333-2222
 Bryan         Weasel  bweasek@live.com    333-444-2235
```

And I'm trying to do something like this:
Add new column with value=1 if first-name and last-name have a duplicate.

```
 Has Dup?     First Name    Last    Email               Phone
 1            Tim           Berly   tim@gmail.com       454-343-2123
 1            Tim           Berly   tim43@gamil.com     343-234-2343
              Mary          Berly   bm@mdmdfm.com       333-212-6996
              Jill          Brown   jbrown@mgasd.com    334-343-3443
 1            Mary          Red     maryr@gmai.com      444-454-4545
 1            Mary          Red     redmary@yahoo.com   333-333-2222
              Bryan         Weasel  bweasek@live.com    333-444-2235
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

After adding the new column, it appears that *First Name* is in B1. In A2, you could add any one of the following formulas,

`=COUNTIFS(B:B, B2, C:C, C2)`

That will produce the number of occurrences for the first and last names (e.g. *1* for single, *2* or more for duplicates).

If you want a more complicated formula with simpler results then perhaps,

`=SIGN(COUNTIFS(B:B, B2, C:C, C2)-1)`

That will produce *0* for single occurrences and *1* for any duplicate, triplicate, etc. This could be expanded to an `IF` statement that leaves an *empty string* for the singles.

`=IF(COUNTIFS(B:B, B2, C:C, C2)>1, 1, "")`

This is the closest to the results you showed in your sample. Any of those should identify the duplicates; it just depends how you want to present the results. The next (and last) option will only show the second (or third, etc) occurrence.

`=IF(SIGN(COUNTIFS(B$2:B2, B2, C$2:C2, C2)>1), 1, "")`

So that does not identify the first occurrence of duplicate values but it does identify the second, third, etc with a *1*.

Fill or copy any of these formulas down column A as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If your names are sorted, you can use

```
=AND($B2=$B3, $C2=$C3)
```

starting in row 3. 
This will report `TRUE` for every row that has the same first and last name as the row above it. 
If you need the result that you show (same as the row above *or below*), set `A2` to

```
=AND($B2=$B3, $C2=$C3)
```

and `A3` to

```
=OR(AND($B2=$B3, $C2=$C3), AND($B3=$B4, $C3=$C4))
```

(and drag down).

If you prefer `1` and `0` over `TRUE` and `FALSE`, begin the formula with `--`; e.g.,

```
=--OR(AND($B2=$B3, $C2=$C3), AND($B3=$B4, $C3=$C4))
```

Note that this answer requires your data to be sorted by first *and last* name.
If you have

```
Tim           Berly   ...
Mary          Berly   ...
Tim           Berly   ...
```

this will not catch it.